# Resource recommendation for geometrical viewpoint of physics

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, algebraic-geometry

I am interested in seeing the geometrical viewpoint of the formulation of quantum field theory and related fields. I have been studying The Geometry of Quantum States and find it a very good approach to studying entanglement. To explore QFT and related fields, I found two books The Geometry of Physics by Frankel and Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics by Schutz. Which of these would be a good starting point and be more accessible?